# Embedded Youtube video stopped working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

I built a site which includes embedded youtube videos. Up until recently they worked on all devices, but recently they have stopped working on iPhones (and iTouch).

The videos play only for few seconds and then just show a black screen. Console show the usual youtube errors, and are the same for chrome on desktop, and safaris on iphone:

Unable to post message to .... Recipient has origin ....

Blocked a frame with origin .... from accessing a frame with origin .... Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

The js to load the video players is addapted from youtube API examples

```
// the width of player
var plwidth = 274;
var plheight = 171;

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

// This is a protocol-relative URL as described here:
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Create an <iframe> (and YouTube player) when the buttons are pressed.    
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    //alert('youtube downloaded');

    var player;

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('playbutton');

    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){        
        buttons[i].style.display = "block";
    }

    // display play buttons
    var button = document.getElementById('playbutton');

    button.onclick = function(){
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: plheight,
            width: plwidth,
            videoId: 'wr7-K42RXh8',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        });
        return false;       
    }

}   

// The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    var videoplaceholder = document.getElementById('videoplaceholder');
    videoplaceholder.style.display = "none";
    event.target.playVideo(); 
    var button = document.getElementById('playbutton');
    button.style.display = "none";          
}
```

Any ideas why it suddenly stopped working on iPhone (it works on iPad)? Any help is really appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method for playing your Youtube videos in UIWebView.

```
-(NSString*)htmlStringForEmbeddingYTVideoWithVideoID:(NSString*)videoId andPlayerWindowSide:(CGSize)playerWindowSize
{
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body  style=\"margin:0 0 0 0\" bgcolor=\"#000000\"><!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. --><div id=\"player\" style=\"height:%dpx; width:%dpx;\"></div><script>var tag = document.createElement('script');tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);var player;function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player', {height: '%d',width: '%d',videoId: '%@', playerVars : { 'showinfo' : 0 },events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady,'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});}   function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo();   }   var done = false;   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {   if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);    done = true;    }   }   function stopVideo() {  player.stopVideo(); }   </script>   </body> </html>",playerWindowSize.height,playerWindowSize.width,playerWindowSize.height,playerWindowSize.width,videoId];
    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply: I'm not familiar UIWebView. I managed to get it working by using playerVars : {
     'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 1,
          'showinfo': 0 
    },

Comment: gr8! if the answer was useful to you, then you can select the tick aside it and make it green. This my reputation. Thanks! :)